# navigation.navigate is not a function

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-stack

I'm using navigation to navigate my react native app and I couldn't Paypass this issue. I did as the docs but nothing works for me.

The problem is I'm trying to use the navigation option to add a header and right button to navigate me to another screen, but it keeps giving me this error: "navigation.navigate is not a function. (in navigation.navigate is undefined)

Here is my code:

```
    static navigationOptions = (navigation) => {
        return {
            title: 'Review Jobs',
            headerRight: (<Title onPress={()=>{navigation.navigate('settings')}}>Settings</Title>)
        };
    };
```

thank you

Comment: Please put the code in your question and convert it to a self-contained example so people can reference this question in the future.

Comment: Although your specific question has already been properly answered (I think), I just want to point out that *if* you're using `useNavigation`, you may get this error if you forget to include parentheses when calling it. Just make sure you remember the parentheses, like so: `const navigation = useNavigation();`.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is a common problem with React, specially when you don't understand the newest JS standard (like ES6, that is used by React).

So, your problem is conceptual here. React components receive a single object, named `props`, that contains all the `props`. Normally, you use the deconstructing form to obtain directly some attributes of props. In this case, you want to have `props.navigation`.

You can deconstruct the props object in the arrow function arguments, that is what the documentation says, with `({navigation}) => ...` instead of `(navigation) => ...`

That is the same as using `(props) => ...` and later do `props.navigation`

You will also need to change your onPress function. Using a `{...}` block in arrow function will not return anything unless you specify `return`. If you doesn't wrap around your body function with `{...}`, then it is the same as writing `{ return ...}`. So, if you want to return `navigation.navigate('settings')`, you have to delete the surrounding `{...}` or write return inside.

```
    static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
        return {
            title: 'Review Jobs',
            headerRight: (<Title onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('settings')}>Settings</Title>)
        };
    };
```

Also, you could do the same with your navigationOptions function:

```
    static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
        title: 'Review Jobs',
        headerRight: (<Title onPress={() => navigation.navigate('settings')}> Settings </Title>),
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

use object destructuring while receiving the parameters as :

```js
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => { // use {} to object destructuring
  return {
   title: 'Review Jobs',
   headerRight: (
      <Title onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('settings')}>
       Settings
      </Title>
   )
   };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `{}` for navigation

```js
static navigationOptions = ( {navigation} ) => {
  return {
    title: 'Review Jobs',
    headerRight: (<Title onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('settings') }}>Settings</Title>)
  };
};
```