# React native - navigation.navigate is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I got this yellow warning message when trying to navigate the through pages.

```
navigation.navigate is not a function
```

My code

```
export default (navigation) => (
  <View>
    <Card>
      <Button
        onPress={() => {
          onSignIn().then(() => navigation.navigate("SignedIn")); //yellow warning message
        }}
      />
    </Card>
  </View>
);
```

This solution not really helping - [navigation.navigate is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52904853/navigation-navigate-is-not-a-function).

Reference: https://github.com/datomnurdin/auth-reactnative

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried to add curly braces around the `navigation`

```
export default ({navigation}) => (
  <View>
    <Card>
      <Button
        onPress={() => {
          onSignIn().then(() => navigation.navigate("SignedIn")); //yellow warning message
        }}
      />
    </Card>
  </View>
);
```